# C++ condition without selection statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, expression, logical-operators

Maybe because of Perl influence, I like using the following syntax

```
condition && do_something();
```

instead of

```
if ( condition )
{
  do_something();
}
```

(I know I could put the latter in one row without braces, but that's not the point.)

I've made several tests (below), which work.
But I couldn't find a reference in the standard, stating that it's legal.
It could be implied in

- 5.14 Logical AND operator
- 5.17 Assignment operators
- 6.4. Selection statements

but I'm not completely sure (I checked C++ 98, sorry to be old fashioned, but probably even C standard would suffice).

NB: I do realize that in order to work, the last expression (do_something) has also to be be convertible to bool, which is not necessary for the selection statement. This is a serious restriction of course.

So the questions are:

1. Is it perfectly legal?
2. Is there a reason not to use it?
3. Are there possible side effects (like optimizations leading to unexpected results)?

Apologies if turns out to be a duplicate, I couldn't find anything, but possibly because I didn't use the right keywords.

```
#include <cassert>

bool sayYes()
{
  return true;
}

bool sayNo()
{
  return false;
}

int main( int args, char* argv[] )
{
  bool a = true;
  bool b = false;
  int i = 0;

  a && ( i = 1 );
  assert( i == 1 );

  !a && ( i = 0 );
  assert( i == 1 );

  ( a || b ) && ( i = 0 );
  assert( i == 0 );

  sayYes() && ( i = 1 );
  assert( i == 1 );

  ( sayNo() || sayYes() ) && ( i = 0 );
  assert( i == 0 );

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think main reason it cannot be used the same way as on perl - C++ requires that result of operation on right must be convertible to `bool`, ie you cannot put any expression on the right unlike you do on perl.

Comment: I thought about that, and edited the question before seeing your comment. Thanks.

Comment: The downside is the difficulty encountered if you ever want to add an "else" clause to the `if (condition)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's perfectly legal. From [expr.log.and]:

> `&&` guarantees left-to-right
>   evaluation: the second operand is not evaluated if the first operand is `false`.

`expr() && fun()` is equivalent to `if (expr()) fun()` (assuming `fun()` returns something convertible to `bool`). That's an extremely important property when it comes to writing compound conditional expressions. For example, only dereferencing a pointer after we know it's valid:

```
if (ptr && ptr->foo()) { ... }
```

That said, if what you really want is:

```
if (expr()) {
    fun();
}
```

just write that. The compiler will generate the same code either way, but the intent of what you're trying to do will be much clearer.

Comment: The use of an unevaluated term after an && has been idiomatic since K&R. I find it commonly used and I continue to use it. It's terse, clear, and fits on one line making more of the source visible in an editor. C++ has complicated matters by allowing && to be overloaded but I can't think of a good reason to overload && without altering the way the language works in unexpected ways.  &, OTOH, can be usefully overloaded to do things like a binary and of a vector of int8_t's for instance to work with extra long binaries.

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes it is legal. An expression followed by `;` is a valid statement.
2. Some folk might find it obfuscating.
3. It cannot be optimised out if there are side effects.

Do be aware though that `&&` can be *overloaded* in C++. If it's overloaded then then the short-cutting property of the operator is discarded. *That* will cause strange effects. It's chiefly for this reason that I would advise against this style.

Comment: There are reasons that this is idiomatic in Perl and not idiomatic in C++. But even if there weren't good reasons, programmers will assume that if you did something in an unusual way, you had a reason, and they will go looking for it. So do things the idiomatic way unless you have a good reason to do otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

I think i am obligated to point this out. 
*What you are trying to do should be avoided at all costs.* You are trying too manipulate the syntax of the language itself too mimic another's. And you are doing this because you're more comfortable with using another syntax for an **if statement**. You can't think like this, at one point this code will be seen by someone else, and they will be utterly confused when they are seeing this weird syntax. If i saw such things in any c++ library that i was going to use i would simply not use it and never worry about it again.

Maybe you decide to name all your variables in camel case, or maybe you think that you should omit the padded whitespace before a `private`, `protected`, or `public` specifier, or maybe you just like putting all your brackets on a new line. That's when you should say:

> ...I like using the following...

But when you decide that you don't like how the language reads an `if-statement` or a function declaration, you have to deal with it. Why? Because that's how it's done, that's how the language was written. What you're trying to do is equivalent to changing a letter of the English alphabet because you're more comfortable with the way the 's' looks in your native language.

Whenever i see `&&` i think one of three things, `r-value`, `universal ref`, and `AND`. Do i think of `if`? NO. Why should I, who says I have ever programmed in Perl before, hey how do you know if I am even familiar with such a syntax?

So basically...

*You're writing in c++, you're not writing in Perl.
Somewhere along the lines you will have to write in a different language, will you then try to manipulate it's syntax as well? Will you even be able to do such a thing, where does this begin, where does it stop?*

Comment: Plus one but do add short-circuit to the three things.

Comment: short circuiting of boolean operations has more to do with *how*  the compiler evaluates an expression, i was pointing out what the operator's main literal meanings were.

Comment: Disagree. I cannot see any manipulation or mimicing here. Exact same syntax works (almost) exact same way. Up to the point that there are people, who find this thing idiomatic in C/C++.

Answer (score 1):

I must confess that I use this technique because it often seems more succinct (at least to me and my colleagues) when coupled with the alternative operator representations.

Consider this (contrived but indicative) example:

```
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <exception>
#include <regex>

struct invalid_number : std::logic_error
{
    using std::logic_error::logic_error;
};

template<class Excep, class...Args>
[[noreturn]]
bool raise(Args&&...args)
{
  throw Excep(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

int parse_number(const std::string& s)
try
{
  const std::regex re("^\\d+$");
  std::regex_match(s, re) or raise<std::invalid_argument>(s);
  return std::stoi(s);
}
catch(...)
{
  std::throw_with_nested(std::invalid_argument(__func__));
}
```